# C# ASP.NET MVC 3 SQL database to html.dropdownlistfor and AutoPostBack to Browse action on selecting and item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, code-first

How to post back selected Category item from html.dropdownlist to the browse action method in the event controller? I am thinking of AJAX and JQuery.

[image]

EVENT CONTROLLER

EventController.cs

```
    //
    // GET: /Event/CategoryMenu
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult CategoryMenu()
    {
        int id = 400;
        ViewBag.Categories = storeDB.Categories.OrderBy(g => g.Name).ToList();
        var cevent = storeDB.Events.Single(a => a.EventId == id);
        return PartialView(cevent);
        //var categories = storeDB.Categories.ToList();
        //return PartialView(categories);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Store/Browse
    public ActionResult Browse(string category)
    {
        // Retrieve Category and its Associated Events from database
        var categoryModel = storeDB.Categories.Include("Events").Single(g => g.Name == category);
        return View(categoryModel);
    }
```

MODEL

EventCalendarEntities.cs

```
public class EventCalendarEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Place> Places { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Category.cs

```
public partial class Category    
{    
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }          
}
```

Event.cs

```
[Bind(Exclude = "EventId")]
public class Event
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Place")]
    public int PlaceId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "An Event Title is required")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
    [Range(0.01, 100.00, ErrorMessage = "Price must be between 0.01 and 100.00")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Event Date is required")]
    [DisplayName("Event Date")]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Start Time is required")]
    [DisplayName("Start Time")]
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "End Time is required")]
    [DisplayName("End Time")]
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Event Place URL")]
    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string EventPlaceUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Place Place { get; set; }
}
```

VIEW

CategoryMenu.cshtml

```
@model MvcEventCalendar.Models.Event    

<p id="categories">  
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category)        
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories,      "CategoryId", "Name", Model.CategoryId), "-- Select Category --")  
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category)  
</p>
```

Browse.cshtml

```
@model MvcEventCalendar.Models.Category
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Browse Events";
}
<div class="genre">
    <h3><em>@Model.Name</em> Events</h3>
    <ul id="album-list">
        @foreach (var theEvent in Model.Events)
        {
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Details", new
                {
                    id = theEvent.EventId
                })">
                <img alt="@theEvent.Title" src="@theEvent.EventPlaceUrl"/>
                <span>@theEvent.Title</span> </a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. NullReference exception was unhandled by user code in line *@Model.Name* Events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to post the selected category when the selection changes you could indeed use AJAX.

I would just add some class and url attributes to the dropdown so that it can be unobtrusively AJAXified in a separate js file:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.Category, 
    new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories, "CategoryId", "Name", Model.CategoryId), 
    "-- Select Category --",
    new { 
        @class = "category", 
        data_browse_url = Url.Action("browse", "event") 
    }
)
```

and then in a separate js file:

```
$(function() {
    $('.category').change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value != null && value != '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).data('browse-url'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: { category: value },
                success: function(result) {
                    // TODO: do something with the returned HTML from the action
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How do I link js file and the cshtml file?

Comment: @user522767, by using a `<script>` tag in your markup pointing to the js file you want to include: `<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/myscript.js")"></script>`.

Comment: I got this exception >> Sequence contains no elements. What value is being posted - is it CategoryId or Name?

Comment: @user522767, where did you get this exception? Is it in the `Browse` method? The .Single method will throw this exception if it finds no records matching the criteria. You may consider using the `.FirstOrDefault` method instead.

Comment: in the browse action                                                 // Retrieve Category and its Associated Events from database
var categoryModel = storeDB.Categories.Include("Events").Single(g => g.Name == category);

Comment: @user522767, that's because there are no records matching your search criteria. Anyway, this has nothing to do with MVC, it's more of a data access problem you are having.

Comment: But I would like to know the kind of value being posted - is it CategoryId or Name?

Comment: @user522767, it's the value, that's what's being sent: `var value = $(this).val();`. It makes more sense to perform queries against the value rather than the name because the name might not be unique.

Comment: I got a NullReference Exception in Browse.cshtml, the view for the Browse action

Comment: @user522767, I guess that's because your controller action passed a null model to it? You should really learn to debug your code. Put breakpoints, ... I mean in your Browse action you are fetching stuff from your database and passing a model to the view. If this model is null and you try to use it you will get such exception. What do you expect me to do?

Comment: I'm just a beginner. The posted value is a string right? like the Name of the selected item in the dropdownlist e.g."Education". If this is the kind of value received by the Browse action

Comment: It is actually returning the index of the selected item as a string e.g. "4". But when the Browse action receives it, the value of the categoryModel that is sent to the event becomes null, which is expected because there is no Name in the Categories database with the value "4" or something. I have tried to typecast the string to int and get the corresponding name for the id but it does nothing.

Comment: @user522767, you could query based on the id, not the name: `var categoryModel = storeDB.Categories.Include("Events").Single(g => g.Id == category);`.

Comment: id is int while category is string. Therefore, I converted the value to an int and used the same query as above but a null is returned for object. I am using the breakpoint to debug. Any advise will be much apreciated.

Comment: Name        Value    Type                                                              category     "3"     string                                                       id            0      int           The id is converted to 0                                        public ActionResult Browse(string category)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt16(category);
   // Retrieve Category and its Associated Events from database
    var categoryModel =storeDB.Categories.Include("Events").Single(g => g.CategoryId == id);
            return View(categoryModel);
        }

Comment: why converting or parsing string to int return zero c sharp?

Comment: The Browse action in the controller is working perfectly now but the Browse.cshtml view  is not rendered.

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov - Is there a way to post the full path of the URL including the value as a get request to the browser, from where the parameter will be sent to Browse action in the Event Controller like so >>>   localhost:54659/Event/Browse?category=8  rather than just sending 8 to Browse action in the controller? I think that way, the Browse.cshtml will be rendered.

Comment: @user522767, I really have hard time understanding your questions. Why are you casting to int? Can't you simply have your Browse action directly take an integer parameter: `public ActionResult Brows(int category) { ... }`? Also when you say that the `Browse.cshtml` view is not rendered what do you mean? What happens instead? Are you getting an exception? If yes what exception?

Comment: I have changed the parameter for Browse action from string to int and it works now. In the first picture above, on selecting an item in the dropdownlist, all events for that category should be displayed in the main body of the layout - the one with "This is the Home Page" but nothing happens on select. I would prefer a situation where i have something like this on the browser >>> localhost:54659/Event/Browse?category=8 . That will send value 8 as to the Browse action in the Event Controller. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can imagine typing the part after 54659 in "localhost:54659/Event/Browse?category=8" in the URL bar